# HTTPS is Not Encrypted? Server will not make a secure connection

Tags: php, apache, https

**May Not Be Safe For Work**

I cannot get my server to make a secure connection.

I created a checkout form here: https://bradp.com/join-30-30-club

When entered, the browser attempts to make a secure connection appears to give up and goes to an unencrypted connection.

What do you think It could be?

I'm using Apache and PHP.

Comment: Works for me, but I didn't get past the validation. You should create a test page with just one form posting to a different php page and displays the post variables.

Comment: Do your httpd logs say anything significant?

Answer (score 1):

Based on the output of the certificates for that site fetched with:

openssl s_client -connect bradp.com:443 -showcerts

on my mac (full output at http://www.atlbbs.com/bradp.txt ) it looks like you might a certificate chain problem. Without seeing your logs, if I had to guess, I'd say you are lacking the extra intermediary certificate that GoDaddy SSL certs usually need to work. If that's all okay, then you can try and chase down the "self signed certificate in certificate chain" or tell your software to ignore that warning. Or find who Valicert is and what they have to do with anything.